# Set up label placement properties using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I have two feature classes and a basemap (group layer). The two feature classes are above the basemap. However, the symbology of the two layers are covered by some labels in the basemap. Now I want to have the two feature classes with Placement Properties--conflict resolution with different feature weight in order to have labels and features from basemap under the two feature classes symbols.

How can I use ArcPy to implement it?
[image]

Comment: Are you using arcmap or PRO?

Comment: Could you please provide more details of what you intend to do? We also appreciate including any attempts at coding, as this also can be helpful in figuring out what you are trying to do. Including any visual examples would be helpful.

Comment: @Geo.Dude ArcMap

Comment: @Aaron I am trying to use python to implement the similar function that can be done in ArcMap. In ArcMap, you can go to properties of a layer--labels--placement property. Under conflict resolution, there is an option to enter the weight value. I would like to use arcpy to implement the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with arcpy.  You would need to look at ArcObjects for that functionality.

As a workaround you could set you desired labelling rules for the feature layer then save it out as a layer file.  You can then use arcpy to apply the layer file to other (similar) feature layers.